# Sleep not working in child process after the popen function call

Tags: c, signals, sleep, popen, sigchld

I have written a small C program which is creating a child process and then running a shell command using popen. I have created a signal handler to wait for the child process to end while the parent process just runs in an infinite loop. When I am calling 'sleep(5)' after the popen system call the sleep call does not work.

Instead if I put the sleep call before the popen then it is working. Also if I remove the signal handler and just wait for the child process in the parent process then there is no problem(i.e. sleep runs properly anywhere).

```
//Assume all required header files and function prototypes added

int main()
{
    int pid,status;
    signal(SIGCHLD,reaper);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
       runCommand();
    while(1);
}

void runCommand()
{
    FILE *pipen;
    char *buffer;

    buffer = (char*) malloc(100);
/*sleep #1*/    sleep(5);
    if ((pipen = popen("uname -a", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("\nError during shell command execution: ");
        exit(0);
    }
/*sleep #2*/    sleep(5);
    fgets(buffer, 100, pipen);
/*sleep #3*/    sleep(5);
    printf("\n%s\n",buffer);
    exit(0);
}

void reaper(int signal)
{
    int status;
    waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG);
}
```

When I am running the above program sleep #1 works and the process sleeps for the given time. I am getting to know this by observing the time it takes to print the result of the command (by the printf statement).
But for sleep #2 and sleep #3 I expect the process to sleep but that does not seem to be happening as the result of the command is printed on the console instantaneously.

The behavior can be observed by keeping only the sleep #2 or sleep #3 call, and removing the other two sleep calls.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How do you know which sleep is being ignored? It only prints once, after everything is done. If it takes less than 15 seconds, you can't tell which one was skipped.

Comment: I am commenting two sleep calls and only keeping one at a time while running.

Comment: A better way would be to put `printf()` calls after each sleep.

Comment: When I test it just sleep #2 is ignored.

Comment: I added printfs before each sleep and as you suggested, and you are right. It only ignored sleep #2. But then when I removed sleep #1 and sleep #2,  it ignored sleep #3.

Comment: Note that `sleep()` returns the number of seconds for which it didn't successfully sleep.  It returns 0, therefore, when it runs its full time; it may return a non-zero amount if it is interrupted (unless perhaps there's less than a second left when it's interrupted).  If you had checked the return value (and perhaps printed it when it is non-zero), you would almost certainly have spotted this.

Answer (score 3):

`popen()` works by forking a child to execute `/bin/sh -c "uname -a"`. When that child exits, the process receives a `SIGCHLD` signal. This interrupts the `sleep()` call and runs your `reaper` function.

I haven't been able to find this mentioned in any Linux or POSIX documentation, but it's in the [SunOS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0213/6m6ne387i/index.html):

> The signal handler for `SIGCHLD` should be set to default when using `popen()`. If the process has established a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, it will be called when the command terminates. If the signal handler or another thread in the same process issues a `wait(2)` call, it will interfere with the return value of `pclose()`. If the process's signal handler for `SIGCHLD` has been set to ignore the signal, `pclose()` will fail and errno will be set to `ECHILD`.

You should set the `SIGCHLD` handler back to the default in the child process.

```
void runCommand()
{
    FILE *pipen;
    char *buffer;

    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);

    buffer = (char*) malloc(100);
/*sleep #1*/    sleep(5);
    if ((pipen = popen("uname -a", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("\nError during shell command execution: ");
        exit(0);
    }
/*sleep #2*/    sleep(5);
    fgets(buffer, 100, pipen);
/*sleep #3*/    sleep(5);
    printf("\n%s\n",buffer);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Seems like the child process created by popen exits after the call to popen is complete. So what does the pclose call do?

Comment: @pranav It calls `waitpid()` to get the exit status of the process, which it then returns as its own value. The child process will be a zombie until you call `pclose()`. But if you have your own `SIGCHLD` handler that reaps the process, `pclose()` will not be able to do this.